# Select count distinct query

Tags: sql, group-by, count, subquery

Writing a query that will give me the total count of an event rather than counting the event every time it happens

Ok so I'm trying to write a query that will count the number of session IDs for that each distinct account id, program id and device id has.So for example. acct id 1 has 3 devices watching the same program with 3 different session IDs. I want my query to give me Acct id 1 has 3 sessions. The current query i have is just listing the number of sessions like this

```
Acct ID 01 Session 1, Acct ID 01 Session 1


SELECT count( DISTINCT source_session_id), acct_id, device_id, program_id,  event_date
FROM TABLE 
WHERE condition 
group by source_session_id, acct_id, device_id, program_id, event_date;
```

I would like the end result of my query to be 
Acct ID 01   # of Sessions 2

Comment: Please add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using. If you read the description of the [tag:sql], it strongly suggests that you include that DBMS-specific tag, as functionality and syntax between them varies. It's a waste of time when people post an answer to your question only to find out it doesn't work for you because you're using a different database. Use the [edit] link to add that tag so that people will be able to help you. Some sample data and the output you'd like to get from that data would also help.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing source_session_id from the Group By clause or you will get a row for each different source_session_id.

```
SELECT count( DISTINCT source_session_id), acct_id, device_id, program_id,  event_date
FROM TABLE 
WHERE condition 
group by acct_id, device_id, program_id, event_date;
```